# Program to retrieve key/message from a multiple times used one time pad

Tags: python, cryptography, web-scraping

I wrote a program to retrieve the key/messages from 10 different ciphers which were all encrypted with the same key with an xor one-time-pad method via crib dragging.

To do this, I wrote a python script which turns a string to test to hex code. Then it xors the 10 cipher strings (200 hex characters each), two at a time. After that it, xors the test string with the 5 xor hashes on each position and then looks via a website whether this is a reasonably good string to go further and try again.

I already tested it and got positive results.

Now when I do it with the real ciphers I got nowhere so far, and I am not sure whether this is because of the script or me not being able to expand on retrieved valid string fragments.

Here is the code, I know that the website lookup is very bad, but I found no other way this fast/easy (to implement, not to run).

**EDIT**: Since I do not think overwriting the code is good, I put it here in case somebody wants to see it: [Gist link](https://gist.github.com/Acru2015/22ffb2514fae1e62af55)

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import codecs
from urllib.error import URLError
import urllib.request

forbiddenSigns = ['{', '}', '[', ']', '(', ')', '?', '=', '%', '_', ';', '-', '^', ':', '<', '>', '|', '!', '`', '´', "'", '\\']

with open("testCiphers.txt") as f:
    ciphers = f.readlines()

ciphers = [s.strip() for s in ciphers]

crib = "the"
cribList = []

for c in crib:
    cribList.append(hex(ord(c))[2:])

cribHash = ''.join(cribList)
cribLength = len(cribHash)

cipherHashList = []
for i in range(0, len(ciphers) - 1):
    cipherHashList.append(int(ciphers[i], 16) ^ int(ciphers[i + 1], 16))

hashResultList = [str(hex(hr))[2:] for hr in cipherHashList]

hexList = []

for hashResultString in hashResultList:
    for i in range(0, len(hashResultString) - cribLength + 1, 1):
        hexList.append(hashResultString[i:i + cribLength])

for ha in hexList:
    cribAttempt = int(cribHash, 16) ^ int(ha, 16)
    cribAttempt = (hex(cribAttempt))[2:].zfill(cribLength)
    clearText = codecs.decode(cribAttempt, "hex")
    if any(s not in str(clearText) for s in forbiddenSigns) and "\\x" not in str(clearText):
        url = 'http://www.morewords.com/contains/' + str(clearText, "ASCII")
        try:
            siteRequest = str(urllib.request.urlopen(url).read())
            if "words found.</strong></p>" in siteRequest:
                print(str(clearText, "ASCII"), end="\n")
        except URLError :
            "error getting webpage"
```

Comment: Can you give us some examples of the "real ciphers" you failed on? (Please say where you got them from too.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## List comprehensions

You use list comprehensions sometimes, and sometimes you use `for ...: someList.append(...)`. This is not consistent. Use list comprehensions as much as you can since you are already building lists (and list comprehensions are slightly faster than `for` loops):

```
cribList = [hex(ord(letter)[2:] for letter in crib]

cipherHashList = [int(ciphers[i],16)^int(ciphers[i+1],16) for i in range(len(ciphers)-1)]

hexList = [hashResultString[i:i+cribLength] for hashResultString in hashResultList for i in range(len(hashResultString) - cribLength + 1)]
```

You can speed things up a little more (maybe at the cost of readability) by using more complex expressions in the list comprehension to avoid creating intermediate lists:

```
hashResultList = [hex(int(ciphers[i],16)^int(ciphers[i+1],16))[2:] for i in range(len(ciphers)-1)]
```

## Naming

Check [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) for the rationale but you’d better use UPPERCASE names for constants such as `FORBIDDEN_SIGNS` or `CRIB` and lower_snake_case for variables such as `hex_list` or `crib_length`.

Some of the variable are named `thingList` and might be improved using `things`.

## Reusability

Make functions to ease testing into the interpreter and/or reusability:

```
def get_crib_hash():
    return ''.join(hex(ord(letter))[2:] for letter in CRIB)
```

change the value of `CRIB` in the interpreter and voilà, every time you (or any function) use `get_crib_hash()` the value is easily updated without having to recompute everything.

For efficiency reasons I recommend using a generator function for file reading.

## Flaws

On my computer, instead of returning `b'test'`:

```
>>> codecs.decode("74657374","hex")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#39>", line 1, in <module>
    codecs.decode("74657374","hex")
LookupError: unknown encoding: hex
```

You can use a more robust approach in the name of `binascii.unhexlify` which is doing exactly what you want.

For your issue with “real ciphers”, you might want to print the clear text first instead of trying to lookup words through a web API. It’ll help understand what is happening.

## Small improvements

- ```
  forbiddenSigns = ['{', '}', '[', ']', '(', ')', '?', '=', '%', '_', ';', '-', '^', ':', '<', '>', '|', '!', '`', '´', "'", '\\']
  ```

  is better written (more resource friendly) as:

  ```
  FORBIDDEN_SIGNS = '{}[]()?=%_;-^:<>|!`´\'\\'
  ```

  and you will still be able to iterate over each symbol.
- `range()` does not need a `0` as first argument (unless you want to specify a step); similarly a step of `1` is the default.
- compute once if you can; e.g: `str(clearText, "ASCII")`.
- consider using an `if __name__ == '__main__':` construct to emphasize on reusability and improve testing in the interactive interpreter.
- [`format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples) is often more efficient for building strings; it can even replace `hex` for your use case.

## Proposed improvements

```
import binascii

FORBIDDEN_SIGNS = '{}[]()?=%_;-^:<>|!`´\'\\'
CRIB = 'the'

def get_crib_hash():
    return ''.join(format(ord(letter), '02x') for letter in CRIB)

def hash_file(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        previous = None
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            try:
                yield format(int(previous, 16) ^ int(line, 16), 'x')
            except TypeError: # for int(None, 16) at first pass
                pass
            previous = line # Yeah, I’ll compute int(this_thing, 16) a second time…
            # Avoiding it is left as an exercise for the reader.

def decipher_file(filename):
    crib_hash = get_crib_hash()
    crib_length = len(crib_hash)
    crib_hash = int(crib_hash, 16)

    for hash_result in hash_file(filename):
        for i in range(len(hash_result) - crib_length + 1):
            attempt = crib_hash ^ int(hash_result[i:i+crib_length], 16)
            attempt = '{0:0{fill}x}'.format(attempt, fill=crib_length)
            yield str(binascii.unhexlify(attempt), 'ASCII')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from urllib.error import URLError
    from urllib.request import urlopen

    for clear_text in decipher_file('testCiphers.txt'):
        # or just print(clear_text)…
        if '\\x' not in clear_text and any(s not in clear_text
                                           for s in FORBIDDEN_SIGNS):
            url = 'http://www.morewords.com/contains/{}'.format(clear_text)
            try:
                response = str(urlopen(url).read())
                if 'words found.</strong></p>' in response:
                    print(clear_text)
            except URLError :
                'error getting webpage'
```

Comment: @GarethRees A for loop that's appending instead of just using a list comprehension does reduce efficiency.

Comment: @GarethRees Somehow, yes. `list.append` _for the sake of building a list out of another one_ is better written as a list comprehension whenever possible.

Comment: @GarethRees I'm actually not sure of the actualy reason, but tests with `timeit` often show that it's faster to use a list comprehension. Approximately 17% faster in the case of the first loop Mathias cited. (This is in Python 2.7, which may affect results)

Comment: Ah, so when you say "efficiency", you mean "speed". (Normally "efficiency" refers to [algorithmic efficiency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmic_efficiency).)

Comment: I revised the opening paragraph accordingly.

Comment: @GarethRees If you're curious the reason is to do with having to call `append` repeatedly in a for loop, while a list comprehension actually creates a local store of the function's bytecode and uses that. [Source](http://blog.cdleary.com/2010/04/efficiency-of-list-comprehensions/)

Comment: Thank you, i put most of your proposed changes into my code, since I don´t think it is good practice to overwrite my original post, here is the link if sbdy wants to see it: https://gist.github.com/Acru2015/22ffb2514fae1e62af55

Comment: Obviously that remark does not stand anymore when you are `append`ind or `update`ing to several data structures out of the same loop.

Comment: Hey, I discovered that `'{0:0{fill}x}'.format(attempt, fill=crib_length)`somehow gave me false results compared to the hex().zfill() method, but I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

You could read the ciphers in a slightly more efficiently. You can use `map` to run a function over each element of a list, which is even faster than a list comprehension. You could directly create `ciphers` here by running `strip` on every element in `f.readlines()`.

```
with open("testCiphers.txt") as f:
    ciphers = map(strip, f.readlines())
```

You call `str` on `clearText` every time it's used, just make it a string from the start.

```
clearText = str(codecs.decode(cribAttempt, "hex"))
```

This saves time and aids readability.

Also Python supports short circuiting. This means that when evaluating a set of conditions (like x and y, x or y etc.) it will only evaluate as much as it needs to. So in this line:

```
if any(s not in str(clearText) for s in forbiddenSigns) and "\\x" not in str(clearText):
```

it will only check `clearText` for `\\x` if the `any` call returns `True`. If `any` returns `False` it already knows the result of `False and any_value` so it will move on. You could save time by putting the faster to evaluate condition first, in this case your `\\x in clearText` is faster since it only checks one thing, while `any` runs over each iteration of `forbiddenSigns`.

```
if "\\x" not in str(clearText) and any(s not in str(clearText) for s in forbiddenSigns):
```

Now that they're flipped you only ever need to call `any` if you haven't found `'\\x'`. Speaking of which, you can use a raw string to avoid that extra backslash. Raw strings basically don't treat a backslash as a special escape character, so instead of needing `'\\x'` you can just use `r'\x'`. The `r` indicates that it's a raw string.

(Note the one exception to this is that you still can't end a string with a backslash, as that still escapes the closing quotation mark)

And lastly, you don't treat errors properly. Look at your exception:

```
    except URLError:
        "error getting webpage"
```

`except URLError` is good! Lots of people make the mistake of using generic errors. But then, you don't do anything. You're just putting in a string but not printing it or raising it as an error. If you want to raise a `URLError` with your custom message, you need to do this:

```
    except URLError:
        URLError("error getting webpage")
```

Comment: i was able to work most of the changes into my code, only for some multiple times str calls I was not able to find a workaround.
If you want to see it, here is the code: https://gist.github.com/Acru2015/22ffb2514fae1e62af55

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about the multiple `str` calls, can you explain? Also if you'd like you could post a new question on here with your updated code. If you do that, make sure to link back here and explain that it's a follow up question. You could probably wait a bit though as you might get more answers still.

Comment: With `str` I meant that only declaring `str(codecs.decode(cribAttempt, "hex"))` avariable once dis not wirk for me at every position in the code.